# Ubuntu NFS 4: How to avoid the clientaddr param being added?

Tags: nfs, loopback

I'm trying to mount distant NFS. This is what I have in /etc/fstab :

```
server.com:/mnt/hdd  /mnt/hdd  nfs rw,tcp  0 0
```

But this param gets added to the mount.nfs args:

```
clientaddr=192.168.x.x
```

Since the client is behind NAT, I need this param to be omitted.
Man nfs says that in that case, NFS 4 would fallback to non-loopback mode.
I've tried

```
server.com:/mnt/hdd  /mnt/hdd  nfs rw,tcp,clientaddr=  0 0
```

But that complains about invalid param value.

How can I make it go away?

Answer (score 0):

As a fallback, I've ended up with

```
nfs ro,tcp,nolock,nocto,vers=3
```

But I'd like to have NFS 4 with locks.